# How to overlay a div (or any element) over a table row (tr)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, overlay

I'd like to overlay a div (or any element that'll work) over a table row (tr tag) that happens to have more than one column.

I have tried a few methods, which don't seem to work.  I've posted my current code below.

I do get an overlay, but not directly over just the row.  I tried setting the overlay top to $divBottom.css('top'), but that is always 'auto'.

So, am I on the right track, or is there a better way of doing it? Utilizing jQuery is fine as you can see.

If I am on the right track, how do I get the div placed correctly?  Is the offsetTop an offset in the containing element, the table, and I need to do some math?  Any other gotchas I'll run into with that?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#lnkDoIt').click(function() {
    var $divBottom = $('#rowBottom');
    var $divOverlay = $('#divOverlay');
    var bottomTop = $divBottom.attr('offsetTop');
    var bottomLeft = $divBottom.attr('offsetLeft');
    var bottomWidth = $divBottom.css('width');
    var bottomHeight = $divBottom.css('height');
    $divOverlay.css('top', bottomTop);
    $divOverlay.css('left', bottomLeft);
    $divOverlay.css('width', bottomWidth);
    $divOverlay.css('height', bottomHeight);

    $('#info').text('Top: ' + bottomTop + ' Left: ' + bottomLeft);
  });
});
```

```css
#rowBottom { outline:red solid 2px }
#divBottom { margin:1em; font-size:xx-large; position:relative; }
#divOverlay { background-color:Silver; text-align:center;  position:absolute; z-index:10000; opacity:0.5; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Overlay Tests</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p align="center"><a id="lnkDoIt" href="#">Do it!</a></p>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="3" style="position:relative">
      <tr>
        <td><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="rowBottom">
        <td><div id="divBottom"><p align="center">This is the bottom text</p></div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="divOverlay" style=""><p>This is the overlay div.</p><p id="info"></p></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You need to make the overlay div have an absolute position. Also use the position() jQuery method for top and left positions of the row - here are the missing pieces:

```
var rowPos = $divBottom.position();
bottomTop = rowPos.top;
bottomLeft = rowPos.left;

//
$divOverlay.css({
    position: 'absolute',
    top: bottomTop,
    left: bottomLeft,
    width: bottomWidth,
    height: bottomHeight
});
```

Comment: His overly already picked up "position: absolute" from his stylesheet. However you're right about using "pos()".

Comment: That appears to do the trick... with one change:

var rowPos = $divBottom.pos();

should be

var rowPos = $divBottom.offset();

.offset() is the top/left in the doc.

Comment: jquery does not have a function named 'pos'. The correct syntax would be $divBottom.position();

Comment: I know this is a pretty old post, and this code works great! However, I was wondering how I could make the overlay work with bootstrap tables (how can the overlay resize width with the divBottom)? Here is a [link to a bootply](http://www.bootply.com/I2VLZ9xT5G) I've been working with. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 15):

Make:

```
div style="position:absolute"

td style="position:relative;display:block"
```

and you don't need jquery.

Comment: How can I select one specific table row out of hundreds?

Comment: +1 This is a much simpler solution and it worked for me. I used a class: `td { position: relative; display: block;} .overlay {position: absolute; white-space: nowrap; z-index: 1000;}` and then applied the class to the first cell: `<tr><td class="overlay">long block of text</td><td>B</td></tr>`

Comment: PS - For IE<8 the position relative must also be applied to the TR.

Answer (score 3):

```
<!--only this the structure you need to make it visible-->


<!-- this is a wrapper -->
<div style="position: relative;"> 
   
    <div style="position: absolute;"> i'm on the top</div> <!-- here the things you want on top -->

 <!-- everything code you want to write -->
    <table></table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure the the outer elements (in this case the table) overflow property is not set to hidden. With the hidden setting on overflow, no overlay will be displayed!

Answer (score 0):

Getting the height and width of an object straightforward.  The hard part for me was the Top and Left coordinates for absolute positioning.

This is the only script that has ever worked reliably for me:

```
function posY(ctl)
{
    var pos = ctl.offsetHeight;
    while(ctl != null){
        pos += ctl.offsetTop;

        ctl = ctl.offsetParent; 
    }

    return pos;
}
function posX(ctl)
{
    var pos = 0;
    while(ctl != null){
        pos += ctl.offsetLeft;

        ctl = ctl.offsetParent; 
    }

    return pos;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
var bottomTop = $divBottom.offset().top;
var bottomLeft = $divBottom.offset().left;
```